# How to optimize this MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

This query was working fine when the database was small, but now that there are millions of rows in the database, I am realizing I should have looked at optimizing this earlier.  It is looking at over 600,000 rows and is Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort (which leads to an execution time of 5-10 seconds).  It is using an index on the field 'battle_type.'

```
SELECT username, SUM( outcome ) AS wins, COUNT( * ) - SUM( outcome ) AS losses
FROM tblBattleHistory
WHERE battle_type =  '0' && outcome <  '2'
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY wins DESC , losses ASC , username ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

Comment: Run EXPLAIN on it. It'll tell you where you should tighten things up.

Comment: One thing you could do is cache the results to file or something and re-cache every X minute(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing would be to make sure you have good indexes (as others have mentioned).

However, it looks like you're creating a leaderboard of some sort for a web page.  My first question would be - do you really need to execute this query in real time?  Could you create a table in your database (or add a wins and losses column to the users table) with the results of this query and simply refresh it periodically?

Answer (score 5):

It appears you need an index on `username, battle_type, outcome` or `username, outcome, battle_type`.

Comment: I tried both and then ran EXPLAIN, but it is still just using battle_type as the index.  Any idea why that would be?  It doesn't show it as a possible key either.

Comment: What's the difference in indexing in different orders?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, both indexes won't be useful here since grouping happens after the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: @Kerry:  Generally, you specify the columns with the most grainularity first, then the columns with lesser grainularity.

Comment: @newtover: Yep, you're right. I guess the next index to try would be outcome, battle_type, username.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: miss once again =), see my answer below.

Comment: Newb questoin, what is granularity?

Comment: @Kerry:  Granularity is a measure of how unique a SQL table column is.  The id column has a high granularity.  Every element is unique.  A column with an extremely low granularity would be a gender column.  The only values are "M", "F", and null.  You want to index columns with high granularity.

Answer (score 3):

Lets see, what you are doing:

1. Find rows that are of battle_type = 0 and outcome < 2
2. Order by username for grouping
3. Compute aggregations and fold rows to distinct usernames
4. Order by dinamically calculated fields

On steps 3 and 4 you have no influence. Step 2 in its current form can not benefit from any indices, since `outcome < 2` is range condition, index on (battle_type, outcome, username) looks very tempting though.

Assuming that `outcome` is enumeration of `0,1,2,3...` you can change the range condition to equality comparison and benefit from index on (battle_type, outcome, username):

```
SELECT username, SUM( outcome ) AS wins, COUNT( * ) - SUM( outcome ) AS losses
FROM tblBattleHistory
WHERE battle_type = 0 AND outcome IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY wins DESC , losses ASC , username ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

If `outcome` is not enumeration, index on (battle_type, outcome) will do. Index on (battle_type) only is excess now, since `battle_type` is a prefix in the compound index.

Comment: This helped some, but it was still looking at over 500,000 rows, so I'm just going to make a table to cache the results and update every 10 minutes.